# Learning functions in Python

Tags: python, syntax-error, calculation

I cannot get this answer correctly formatted. I keep getting a Syntax error message.

```
ratio(1+**5)/2
print(ratio)
```

I am so new! And I really don't even know where to look to fix my errors. Thank you if you're willing to help.

Comment: what's `**5` supposed to mean?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What output do you expect?

Comment: The downvotes are not meant to discourage your coding. This question is probably going to get downvoted and closed because it will not be helpful to others in the future. But, if you edit this question to clarify your question, you may be able to get good feedback that helps. We would like to help, but I don't think anyone is sure what 1+**5 means. @nectarBee 's answer is hopefully of some help to you and good luck with learning python. There should be an edit button/link below your question that you can select to change your question.

Comment: For this syntax error see: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/arithmetic_operators_example.htm for how to format your code. Also tutorialspoint.com has a lot of python pages that can help going forward.

Comment: @Rorschach Indeed, I completely agree with you. Downvoting gives a clue to the catechist about how to raise a question, or error with minimal reproducible information. In fact, don't be discouraged if you are newby to stackoverflow and python, it is just a part of your learning curve (it is valid for everyone). When I first started to visit stackoverflow, I learned and still I am learning from many experienced programmers. So I decided to do the same for others who are beginners and looking for help. So keep on asking questions.  Enjoy python..!

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
x = 2
ratio = (x**5)/2
print(ratio)
```

always left to the equal symbol (`=`) is the variable name in which the value being assigned. In fact `ratio` is your variable name. By assigning different values to `x`, you can play with.

Comment: Thank you for trying. Learning Python online is hard. This is all the information for the problem I received. It is like trying to learn algebra when the rules are not explained, like the order of operations for example.

Comment: I recommend to follow a good reference book for Python and then to follow a course online (since you mentioned ‘learning Python online’). There good books explain Python programming step by step. If you interested, let me know and I can share you a book.